# How to split input json array in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

How can i acheve the below split in Apache nifi

my input json is

```
[
{
  "quality": true,
  "tagname": "P1001",
  "timestamp": 1543295658092,
  "value": 121
},
{
  "quality": true,
  "tagname": "P1002",
  "timestamp": 1543295658092,
  "value": 23
}
]
```

my output should be 2 seperate json

1.

```
{
  "quality": true,
  "tagname": "P1001",
  "timestamp": 1543295658092,
  "value": 121
}
```

2.

```
{
  "quality": true,
  "tagname": "P1002",
  "timestamp": 1543295658092,
  "value": 23
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you need to split the json array, but keep in mind that NiFi can use it directly as a recordset without the need of splitting it, this will lead to a better performance.

Answer (score 5):

Use **`SplitJson`** processor with below configs:

[image]

Now processor **split the array of json** into individual flowfiles.

Comment: I would note that it sometime takes multiple `SplitJSON` processors to get down to the level that one may want